# How to display contents under a heading in a webpage without repeating the header in Yii2?

Tags: html, arrays, for-loop, foreach, yii2

I want to pass an array to my view  that contain some heading and some contents list under it.

My array is like this:

```
    Array
     (
      [0] => Array
     (
        [trimester] => Trimester1
        [subject] => ABC
     )

     [1] => Array
     (
        [trimester] => TrimesterII
        [subject] => CDF
     )

     [2] => Array
     (
        [trimester] => TrimesterIII
        [subject] => FGH
     )

     [3] => Array
     (
        [trimester] => TrimesterIV
        [subject] => XYZ
     )
     [4] => Array
     (
        [trimester] => TrimesterI
        [subject] => PQR
     )
     [5] => Array
     (
        [trimester] => TrimesterI
        [subject] => FGH
     )
     [6] => Array
     (
        [trimester] => TrimesterII
        [subject] => MNO
     )


   )
```

I want to dispaly the contents like this:

```
    Trimester1
    ABC
    PQR
    FGH
    Trimester2
    CDF
    MNO
    Trimester3
    FGH
    Trimester4
    XYZ
```

View:

```
                <?php

                     $old = "";
                     foreach ($curriculum_list as $a)
                     {
                         if ($old != $a->trimester)
                         {
                             $old = $a->trimester;
                         ?>
                    <tr class="odd">

                    <td>

                    <h4><?=$a->trimester;?></h4>

                    </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr class="even">

                    <td valign="top">

                    <ul>

                    <li><?=$a->subjects;?></li>

                    </ul>

                    </td>

                    </tr>

                <?php }
                         else
                         {
                         ?>

                <tr class="even">

                    <td valign="top">

                    <ul>

                    <li><?=$a->subjects;?></li>

                    </ul>

                    </td>

                    </tr>

                <?php }}?>

                </table>
```

But I get the answer like this:

```
        Trimester I
        ABC
        Trimester II
        CDF
        Trimester III
        FGH
        Trimester IV
        XYZ
        Trimester I
        PQR
        FGH
        Trimester II
        MNO
```

That is I want to display the contents(subjects) under the headings(trimester) without repeating the headings(trimester).
How can I solve this???

Comment: provide code that you did

Comment: It is mentioned in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array name is `$arr`

first **sort** it by **trimester**

```
ArrayHelper::multisort($arr, ['trimester'], [SORT_ASC]);
```

to use array helper add  ArrayHelper class as below

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
```

Code in controller :

```
  ArrayHelper::multisort($arr, ['trimester'], [SORT_ASC]);

  $data=array();
  $temp_arr=array();
  $i=0;$j=0;$k=0;
  foreach ($arr as $value)
  {
    if(!in_array($value['trimester'],$temp_arr))
    {
      $j=0;
      $temp_arr[]=$value['trimester'];
      $data[$i]['trimester']=$value['trimester'];
      $data[$i]['sub'][$j] = $value['subject'];
      $k=$i;$j++;$i++;
    }
    else
    {
      $data[$k]['sub'][$j] = $value['subject'];
      $j++;
    }
  }
```

It will give you following array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [trimester] => TrimesterI
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ABC
                    [1] => PQR
                    [2] => FGH
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [trimester] => TrimesterII
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [0] => CDF
                    [1] => MNO
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [trimester] => TrimesterIII
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [0] => FGH
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [trimester] => TrimesterIV
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [0] => XYZ
                )

        )

)
```

Code in your view ( manage as your need ) :

```
<?php
foreach ($data as  $value) {
  ?>
  <h4><?=$value['trimester']?></h4>
  <?php
      foreach ($value['sub'] as $subject)
      {
        ?>
        <li><?=$subject?></li>
        <?php
      }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. $newArr will be the answer.

```
$newArr = [];
foreach ($Curriculum as $option) {
  $tri = $option['trimester'];
  $sub = $option['subjects'];
  $new= $option['name'];

  $newArr[$trimester][$subjects] = $new;
}
```

Comment: There is no field 'name' in $option